# Fill in NA's based on logic for the whole day

Tags: r, algorithm, na

I did a really poor job asking this question the first time around and apologize.  I've simplified the question and hopefully this makes more sense!

My goal is to create a script that assigns the NA's in master_df_ex$ls_flag so that the sum of ls_flag is 0 for each asof_dt.

I have a algorithm that has 3 columns: date, rank, updn_flag, ls_flag.  The rank  and updn_flag are determined by another algorithm.  The ls_flag takes the updn_flag only if the rank is in the top 50% (in this case, since it's 4, then for rank less than or equal to 2, we use updn_flag for the ls_flag.)

```
asof_dt<-c("2014-10-01","2014-10-01","2014-10-01","2014-10-01",
               "2014-10-02","2014-10-02","2014-10-02","2014-10-02",
               "2014-10-03","2014-10-03","2014-10-03","2014-10-03")
rank_mag<-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
updn_flag<-c(-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1)
ls_flag  <-c(-1,-1,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,-1,1,NA,NA)
master_df_ex<-data.frame(asof_dt,rank_mag,updn_flag,ls_flag)
master_df_ex<-group_by(master_df_ex,asof_dt)

arrange(master_df_ex,asof_dt,rank_mag)

> arrange(master_df_ex,asof_dt,rank_mag)
      asof_dt rank_mag updn_flag ls_flag
1  2014-10-01        1        -1      -1
2  2014-10-01        2        -1      -1
3  2014-10-01        3         1      NA
4  2014-10-01        4        -1      NA
5  2014-10-02        1         1       1
6  2014-10-02        2         1       1
7  2014-10-02        3         1      NA
8  2014-10-02        4        -1      NA
9  2014-10-03        1        -1      -1
10 2014-10-03        2         1       1
11 2014-10-03        3        -1      NA
12 2014-10-03        4        -1      NA
```

Again, my goal is to create a script that assigns the NA's in master_df_ex$ls_flag so that the sum of ls_flag is 0 for each asof_dt.

For 2014-10-01, since both assigned ls_flags are -1, then both NA's should be -1.

For 2014-10-02, since both assigned ls_flags are 1, then both NA's should be -1.

For 2014-10-03, since there's one of each, I want 3 to take the updn_flag's -1 first, then 4 to have whatever that makes the sum on the day 0 (in this case, 1).

One caveat to note is that I don't want to hardcode 4 per day.  It may vary in numbers from day to day.

I am not sure if I need to do a loop or create another work table to make this work.  Please let me know.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your question:
You say "the sum of ls_flag is 0 for each asof_dt" so i think for 2014-10-01 it should be 1 then, shouldn't it.

If i am right you could use the following function:

```
require(dplyr)

   flag_function <- function(ls_flag){
      ind <- which(is.na(ls_flag))
      na_count <- length(ind)
      count <- sum(ls_flag[-ind])
      ls_flag[ind] <- c(rep(-sign(count), abs(count)), 
                        rep_len(c(-1,1), na_count-abs(count)))
      ls_flag
    }

master_df_ex %>%
  group_by(asof_dt) %>%
  mutate(ls_flag = flag_function(ls_flag))
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
Groups: asof_dt

      asof_dt rank_mag updn_flag ls_flag
1  2014-10-01        1        -1      -1
2  2014-10-01        2        -1      -1
3  2014-10-01        3         1       1
4  2014-10-01        4        -1       1
5  2014-10-02        1         1       1
6  2014-10-02        2         1       1
7  2014-10-02        3         1      -1
8  2014-10-02        4        -1      -1
9  2014-10-03        1        -1      -1
10 2014-10-03        2         1       1
11 2014-10-03        3        -1      -1
12 2014-10-03        4        -1       1
```

Checking for sum==0

```
master_df_ex %>%
  group_by(asof_dt) %>%
  mutate(ls_flag = flag_function(ls_flag)) %>%
  summarise(sum(ls_flag))
```

Works:

```
     asof_dt sum(ls_flag)
1 2014-10-01            0
2 2014-10-02            0
3 2014-10-03            0
```

Comment: Yes you are right about my questino.  Thank you much.  I am getting: Error: could not find function "%>%"  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `install.packages("magrittr","dplyr")` and then `require(dplyr)` before running the code

Comment: Thank you Floo0.  This works well with 4 records per day (the rank column).  I increased it to 6, and it failed to succeed: Error in flag_function(c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA, -1)) : 
  could not find function "error"  Any thoughts?  almost there, thank you so much!